# Tooltip for every item in dropdown in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, tooltip

I set the DrawMode property to **OwnerDrawFixed** and use the below code for the tooltip for each item in Combobox. I get System.Data.DataRow as Items in my ComboBox also in the tooltip. How can I fix this issue?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem

        If e.Index = -1 Then
            Return
        End If

        e.DrawBackground()
        Dim p As New Point
        p = New Point(ComboBox1.Location.X + 120, ComboBox1.Location.Y + ComboBox1.Height + (30 + e.Index * 10))

        If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
            ToolTip1.Show(ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString, Me, p)
        End If

        ' e.DrawBackground()
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString, e.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))

    End Sub
```

Comment: If the `ComboBox.DataSource` is a DataTable, you should see `System.Data.DataRowView` as the type. If your `ComboBox.Items` is a collection of `DataRowView` objects, then the current Item's DataRow is `Dim itemRow = CType(ComboBox1.Items(e.Index), DataRowView).Row`, so you can build a string from the `Row.ItemArray` with `ToolTip1.Show(String.Join(" - ", itemRow.ItemArray), Me, p)`. If you have set the `ComboBox1.DisplayMember`, the the curren item text is `dim itemText = itemRow(ComboBox.DisplayMember).ToString()`. You can draw that string.

Comment: Note that the vertical position of the ToolTip will be off, since `e.Index * 10` doesn't, probably, calculate correctly the Item height. So you may want the `(e.Index * ComboBox1.ItemHeight)` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString` is invoking `.ToString()` on the underlying `Type` of Items(e.Index). It looks like you are binding the ComboBox to a DataTable, so the underlying `Type` of anything in Items is a DataRow. Invoking `ToString()` on a DataRow will production the value of `System.Data.DataRow`.

Instead, you have to pull the value you want from the desired column of the DataRow, and put that value in your ToolTip.